# CW structure of $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Surprisingly I didn’t find this question although I am sure it must have been asked.

As the title suggests I want to define CW structure on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. I wanted to generalize the following construction for $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

$\mathbb{R}P^n \cong D^n /\text{~}$ where the relation glues together diametrically opposed points on $\partial D^n$. So there is an obvious attaching map $D^n \to \mathbb{R}P^n$.

For $\mathbb{C}P^n$ it is also true that $\mathbb{C}P^n \cong D^{2n+1}/ \text{~}$ but here the relation is nontrivial not only on $\partial D^{2n+1}$ but everywhere so the map $\operatorname{Int} D^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{C}P^n$ is not injective hence not homeomorphism.

So what do I do?

Comment: You need to use $D^{2n}$ instead of $D^{2n+1}$. The boundary gets identified to $S^{2n-1}/S^1\cong \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$. The correct quotient map is still injective on the open ball.

Comment: I still don’t get it. Ok, we can map the boundary as you suggest but what about the interrior?

Comment: $\Phi(z_1,\dots,z_n)=[z_1,\dots,z_n,\sqrt{1-|z|}]$, where $(z_1,\dots,z_n)\in D^{2n}\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $|z|=|z_1|^2+\dots+|z_n|^2$. Note that when $|z|<1$ there is a unique representative for $\Phi(z)$ whose last coordinate is real.